# Override WordPress user with Oauth2 account

Tags: plugins, users, oauth

I am trying to set up WordPress as an OAuth2 client. All of our users are stored in our proprietary CMS which is an OAuth provider. We have very little (to no) users in our WordPress database, primarily just administrators. Ideally, I do not want to store user data in the WordPress database because I would need to somehow maintain state across X number of WordPress sites, whereas I have one source of truth within our proprietary CMS.

My initial design of this so far was to create a plugin that overrides the existing WordPress user functionality and stores an OAuth access token and user uuid within a cookie or session. But, I need this user to be accessible in other plugins, so ideally overriding the default WordPress user methods.

Is this an acceptable approach? Or, am I trying to work with WordPress in a way that it wasn't meant to be worked?

I can find tons of plugins for setting WordPress up as an OAuth2 provider, but very few as a client. That being said, I have found some that do set up WordPress as a client, but a lot of them are specific to Google Apps, Facebook, Twitter, etc. Moreover, these apps rely on storing user data locally within the WordPress user table. I would prefer not to do so.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hi Nick, Welcome to WPSE. Unfortunately I can't help you with the actual issue at hand - but could you please remove the intro (not really relevant for the issue) and maybe add what you've already tried maybe even adding some code. This makes it easier for everyone to help. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @kraftner for the hasty response. I haven't written much code because I'm trying to do some design/research first and I guess I was looking for affirmation with my idea. However, it seems like I should get a proof of concept up and running. Sorry if I took the wrong approach here. I'll try to do some work and post with smaller issues and some work examples.

Comment: Didn't want to upset you, I really just thought that as you are new I'd tell you that you'll get more and better responses if you're question is short and focused instead of telling a story with irrelevant information.

Comment: @kraftner not upset at all sir!

Comment: @kraftner oops, I hit enter too soon. No not upset at all! I appreciate the advice on direction. I want to ask questions as best I can so I can get good responses. So, thank you for your help. I apologize if it came off as nasty, it was very much not meant to be. I'm an overly nice person I promise!!!

Comment: "I can find tons of plugins for setting Wordpress up as an OAuth2 provider, but very few as a client." - FWIW [this is the one I'm using](https://wordpress.org/plugins/openid/) which is both client and provider, using a bundled copy of PHP OpenID

Comment: [Have you seen this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/104347/wordpress-as-a-oauth-provider)?

Comment: This might be a duplicate of https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/50281/51462

Answer (score 1):

If you can stick to overriding just functions that are located in wp-includes/pluggable.php then you should be able to avoid any kind of plugin conflicts ... unless you are using plugins that are overriding the same pluggable functions.

Just make sure that your functions are declared before pluggables is loaded. Plugins are loaded before the pluggables file ... so if you define your function overrides in a plugin then you can be certain they are loaded. Otherwise just make sure to use an earlier action to do so.

There are quite a few authentication, cookie, and user related functions in there for use.

Answer (score 0):

We created an OAuth2 client, completely open source: https://wordpress.org/plugins/lana-sso/

This was created primarily for our Lana Passport OAuth2 Server WordPress plugin. But it's well documented, and follows OAuth standards, so you might be able to use it.

#### The idea

Your idea of not storing users in the WordPress database just unnecessarily overcomplicates things. The concept is understandable, but it cannot be realized. Everything else in WordPress uses the user database, including WordPress core, even plugins, and it would be much more difficult to rewrite it than store user data in the database (and synchronize it).

Of course, it is possible to completely rewrite the user section if you have a very unique goal with the website. But I don't recommend it.

#### The functions

If you receive the user data from the OAuth server, you have to insert a new user:

```php
/**
 * userdata for insert user
 * from oauth2 resource
 */
$userdata = array(
    'user_login' => $userdata_from_server['user_login'],
    'user_pass'  => wp_generate_password(),
    'user_email' => $userdata_from_server['user_email'],
);

/** create user */
$user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata );
```

Then you have to log the user into the WordPress:

```php
wp_clear_auth_cookie();
wp_set_current_user( $user_id );
wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id );
```

Then you need to set the user and the cookie. You need to use these two functions: `wp_set_current_user()` and `wp_set_auth_cookie()`.

Note: WordPress plugins will later query the user with the `wp_get_current_user()` function. And check capability with the `current_user_can()` function, which uses the previously mentioned function.

Let's see what happens at the next login when the user already exists.

If the user is already stored in the database, you can query it based on username with the `username_exists()` function:

```php
/** get user id by username */
$user_id = username_exists( $userdata_from_server['username'] );

wp_clear_auth_cookie();
wp_set_current_user( $user_id );
wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id );
```

And you have to log the user into the WordPress in the same way.

It is easily possible to update the user's data (such as name, biographical information) based on the data received from the OAuth server during login if the user exists.
So you can synchronize user data with Single Sign On login.