# Use Wordpress with a custom OAuth2 provider

Tags: plugins, login, authentication, oauth

I have a fresh Wordpress installation and a working OAuth2 server in Node.js (made using oauth2orize).

The only plugins I've been able to find let me use only the well-known OAuth2 endpoints such as Google, Facebook, Twitter and so forth.

Is there a way for me to use this custom OAuth2 server for authentication on Wordpress?

Comment: I think there is plugin for custom OAuth, but google for it, cuz I forgot name of plugin

Comment: If I found it by googling, I wouldn't ask here

Comment: Well sorry mate, nobody will google-it for you.

Comment: I'm saying I already googled it and I found nothing

Comment: I also looked, and did not find.  I found wp-oath plugin but that is not customizable.  I found Keyring, but that seems to be more for people who want the website to login to a social site (like make posts from twitter.) No dice on a plugin that works.

Comment: This might be a duplicate of https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/50281/51462